# NodeJS + React + Next Framework adding a path to the route

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, routes, next.js

I'm attempting to setup a NodeJS application that is using the Next framework to utilize client and server side rendering.  I'm trying to get the client and server side rendering to prepend a path to the routes/URLs it generates.  The server side render seems to be working by setting up the express server `GET` function to listen for requests made on route and then passing that along to node by stripping out the prepended route value.  However when it comes the rendering on the client the prepended value is missing even when the `as="{somestring}"` is added to the .js pages for elements like `Link` so when the external Next javascript files are referenced in the render it's missing the prepended value.

The purpose for the routing is to allow us to run multiple micro-services on one domain each hosted on different instances in AWS and being routed using Target Groups and an ALB.

Essentially what I want to do is replace **/** with **/{somestring}** and I need this to be included not only in the server side rendering but in the client side rendering.

URL Example:
www.example.com -> www.example.com/somestring

HTML Render:
www.example.com/_next/960d7341-7e35-4ea7-baf6-c2e7d457f0db/page/_app.js -> www.example.com/somestring/_next/960d7341-7e35-4ea7-baf6-c2e7d457f0db/page/_app.js

**Edit/Update**

I've tried to use app.setAssetPrefix and while it renders the requests for the assets correctly and the pages load the assets themselves are 404ing.

Here is my server.js file:

```
const express = require('express');
const next = require('next');

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
const app = next({ dev });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

app
  .prepare()
  .then(() => {
    // Port
    const server = express();
    app.setAssetPrefix('test1');
    // ======
    // Routes
    // ======

    server.get('/test1/:id', (req, res) => {
      const actualPage = `/${req.params.id}`;
      const queryParams = { id: req.params.id };

      app.render(req, res, actualPage, queryParams);
    });

    server.get('/test1', (req, res) => {
      app.render(req, res, '/');
    });

    server.get('*', (req, res) => {
      handle(req, res);
    });

    // =============
    // End of Routes
    // =============

    server.listen(port, err => {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log(`>Listening on PORT: ${port}`);
    });
  })
  .catch(ex => {
    console.error(ex.stack);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need custom routing. Parse the incoming url and replace it with what you want.

Here is is an example to make /a resolve to /b, and /b to /a

https://github.com/zeit/next.js#custom-server-and-routing

Comment: That doesn’t seem to serve the next is assets even though they are rendered correctly